# Linq GroupBy().Select() with complex type - can't work out syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complex join of a number of objects which results in a "list" of populated intersection objects...

```
class Intersect
{
    public Subject Subj { get; set; }
    public Article Art { get; set; }
    public TopicArticle TopArt { get; set; }
    public Topic Top { get; set; }
}

var intersections = System
    .Where(s => s.SystemID == systemID)
    .Join(Subject,
<snip>
```

That part works fine and the assembled data is correct. What I want to do next is group by the Top.ID, while returning Count(Sys.ID) and Top.Name.  I get this far...

```
intersections.GroupBy(g => g.Top.ID)
```

...but the .Select() gives the error "*The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly*", then shows two alternatives - one for IQueryable and one for IEnumerable.  Likewise .Count() gives an "*Ambiguous*" error.

I'm lost! This is a part of linq that is beyond me, could someone please help me with the syntax of this, I just can't find a comparable example anywhere that can put me right.

Much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq probably close to what you want, change the function for the groupby to count.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find a suitable set of posts which enabled me to build a solution for this.

@hkf didn't see that one but it helped confirm that I was on the right track, cheers for that.

Solution I came up with (thanks in no small part to LinqPad)...

```
    .GroupBy(q => new {q.Top.Name, q.Top.TopicID })
    .Select(group => new
                       {
                           id = group.Key.TopicID,
                           name = group.Key.Name,
                           count = group.Count()
                       });
```

Now it works I just have to fully understand it(!).